# How to compare two input values onkey jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have a form with two input fields.

```
<input type="text" id="first" value="">
<input type="text" id="second" value="">
```

I have tried this but no success

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var fst=$("#first").val();
    var sec=$("#second").val();
    if (sec>fst) {
        alert("Second value should less than first value");
        return true;
    }
})
</script>
```

How to allow only second input values are only numbers and also less than the first input

Comment: Some code examlpes are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the key up event.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#first, #second").on("keyup", function () {
    var fst=$("#first").val();
    var sec=$("#second").val();
    if (Number(sec)>Number(fst)) {
      alert("Second value should less than first value");
    return true;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" value="">
<input type="text" id="second" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks it's working,  instead of alert, the second element values should not be allowed onkeyup

Comment: You'd be better off alerting the user through a div because just not allowing it leads to very obnoxious behavior.